# SQL - select * given a count value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select * from two tables (a and b) using a join (column a.id and b.id), given that the count of a column (b.owner) in b is lower than 3, i.e. the occurences of a person's name can be max 2.

I've tried:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  COUNT(b.owner) AS b_count

FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id

GROUP BY b.owner
HAVING COUNT(b_count) <3
```

As I'm pretty new to SQL, I'm pretty stuck here. How can i resolve this issue?
The result should be all columns for owners who do not appear more than twice in the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using? SQL Server and PostgreSQL are completely different products. What have you tried to solve the problem? Why didn't it work? What is the problem you are actually trying to solve (you don't explain what it is). **Consumable** sample data (not images) and expected results, along with your attempts will help us help you. I suggest taking the [tour] as well, as you are yet to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you say "*I'm trying to select * from two tables (a and b)*", but from your attempt I am guessing you only need to return `a`'s columns.

I am also assuming that all IDs in `a` exist in `b` too.

If both assumptions are correct, then the `LEFT JOIN` is an overkill. The simplest solution is a semijoin (`IN` clause) with all IDs from `b` that satisfy the condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM b
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(owner) < 3
)
```

Notice that you don't even need to use table prefixes to refer to columns, because each sub-query deals with only one table at a time.

**EDIT:**

A comment below clarifies that all columns from `a` and `b` should be returned.

In that case, you need an inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE b.id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM b
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(owner) < 3
);
```

Notes:

- There is still a semijoin with a sub-query selecting the IDs with the desired condition. The reason for making this a sub-query is to avoid that the count ends up in the result columns. This way you can just select the desired IDs and then forget about the count. It is conceptually cleaner than trying to do everything in one query, and any decent optimizer would make this as efficient as it should be.
- In your attempt you used a `LEFT JOIN`. That is not what you want here. You would use a `LEFT JOIN` if you wanted all IDs from `a` in your result, even when they don't match any ID from `b`.

Comment: your first assumption is incorrect: i want all columns from b too, second assumption is correct!

Comment: @E.vanDongen is this not what you were looking for?